# Linear Algebra problem proof check

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose V and W are finite-dimensional and U is a subspace of V. Show that there exists a linear map T from V to W such that $\ker T =U$ if and only if $\dim U \geq \dim V- \dim W$.

Here is my proof,

Suppose such linear map exist $T\in \mathscr{L}(V,W)$ and $U=\ker T$, then by the fundamental theorem of linear maps, we have $$\dim V=\dim \ker T +\dim range T=\dim U+\dim range T
$$
since $\dim W\geq \dim range T$
$$\dim V\leq \dim U +\dim W$$

Conversely, suppose $\dim V=n,\dim W=m$, where $n,m< \infty $ and $\dim U =k \geq n -m$

Let$w_1,\dots,w_m$ be basis for $W$, $v_1,\dots,v_k$ be basis for U, since $U$ is a subspace for $V$, we can extend the basis to $v_1,\dots,v_k,v_{k+1},\dots,v_n$ to a basis of $V$,

Now, define $T:V\rightarrow W$,

$T(\sum^n_{i=1}a_iv_i) = \sum^k_{i=1}a_i0+\sum^n_{j=k+1}a_jw_{j-k}$

Let $v,u \in V, \lambda \in \mathbb{F}$, where $\mathbb{F}$ is a field , then $v=a_1v_1+\dots+a_kv_k+a_{k+1}v_{k+1}+\dots+a_nv_n$ and $u=b_1v_1+\dots+b_kv_k+b_{k+1}v_{k+1}+\dots+b_nv_n$, where $a_i,b_i \in \mathbb{F}, \forall \in \{1,\dots,n\}$

We have $T(\lambda v + \lambda u)=T(\lambda a_1v_1+\dots+ \lambda a_kv_k+\lambda a_{k+1}v_{k+1}+\dots+\lambda a_nv_n+\lambda b_1v_1+\dots+\lambda b_kv_k+\lambda b_{k+1}v_{k+1}+\dots+\lambda b_nv_n)$

$=\lambda a_{k+1}w_{k+1}+\dots+\lambda a_nw_n+\lambda b_{k+1}w_{k+1}+\dots+\lambda b_nw_n$
$=\lambda Tv +\lambda Tu$, Hence T is linear.

Now, let $u\in U$, then $u=a_1v_1+\dots a_kv_k$ hence $Tu=0$ and $u \in \ker T$, conversely suppose $0\neq v \in \ker T$, then $T(v)=T(a_1v_1+\dots+a_kv_k+a_{k+1}v_{k+1}+\dots+a_nv_n)=a_{k+1}w_{k+1}+\dots +a_nw_v=0$ , since $w_j,j\in\{k+1,\dots, n\}$ are linearly independent, we must have $a_j=0,\forall j\in \{k+1,\dots,n\}$, hence $v=a_1v_1+\dots +a_kv_k \in U$. Completing the proof.
But I didn't use the assumption k>n-m so I'm not sure where went wrong.

Comment: Your definition of $T$ requires $\dim(W)=m\geq n=\dim(V)$. For instance, what would you do if $V=\mathbb{R}^2$, $U$ is the trivial subgroup, and $W=\mathbb{R}$? Your definition would not make any sense, since you are saying you would first pick a basis $w_1$ for $W$, then map $a_1v_1+a_2v_2$ to $a_1w_1+a_2w_2$....  (Also, the indexing is incorrect, as there is not $v_0$). Given that requirement, $n-m\lt 0$, so $n-m\lt k$ would hold. But this isn't good enough for what you want.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin, thanks for the correction I fixed the index on the sum, but if $V=\mathbb{R}^2, W=\mathbb{R}$ then $\dim U = k\geq 2-1=1$, but trivial subspaces have dimension 0, doesn't satisfy the inequality.

Comment: ahh I see, you are saying that's why we need $k\geq n-m$.

Comment: My point is that your definition only makes sense when $m\geq n$, so you are implicitly assuming $m\geq n$. In fact, your definition does not even work if $V=\mathbb{R}^2$, $U$ is the $X$-axis, and $W$ is $\mathbb{R}$, because picking $v_1=(1,0)$, $v_2=(0,1)$, you are telling me to map $a(1,0)+b(0,1)$ to $bw_2$, but *there is no $w_2$*.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin understood, thanks for explaining , perhaps if I change the definition from mapping on the second sum to $\sum^n_{k+1}a_jw_{j-k}$, would this work?

Comment: Yes, because that would only require $m\geq n-k$, which is equivalent to $k\geq n-m$, exactly the condition you have.